# django display reverse m2m in admin including null

Tags: django, admin

I'm trying to display the reverse M2M relationship in the admin i.e. for the below models, not just display for a given service the region(s) it covers, but I also want to see for a given region what services there are.  Also the same for payment types.  For the reverse views it would be good to see what null entries,  e.g. in payment types click on null and see what services have not been assigned payment types yet.   (I seem to have this in some services even though I haven't specified null=true in the ManytoManyField declarations, - not sure if M2M fields allow this by default?)

```
class Service(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier)
    payment_methods = models.ManyToManyField(PaymentMethod)
    region = models.ManyToManyField(Region)

class Region(models.Model):
    unique_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.unique_id)

class PaymentMethod(models.Model):
    MONTHLY_DIRECT_DEBIT = 'MDD'
    CASH_OR_CHEQUE = 'CAC'
    QUARTERLY_DIRECT_DEBIT = 'QDD'
    PAYMENT_CHOICES = (
        (MONTHLY_DIRECT_DEBIT, 'Monthly Direct Debit'),
        (CASH_OR_CHEQUE, 'Cash or Cheque'),
        (QUARTERLY_DIRECT_DEBIT, 'Quarterly Direct Debit'),
    )
    unique_id = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=PAYMENT_CHOICES)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
```

Comment: So what you need is, to see related `Service` objects with given `Region` object?

Comment: yes basically. that should do it.